# Number of triangles in the figure

Tags: geometry

How many triangles are in the figure show here:

[image: Figure for Problem]

I tried using casework, but it got really messy really fast. I also think that you could easily miscount and get something wrong.

Comment: This is easier because there are no internal triangles; just squares.  All triangles have a base on the edges.  The base can be 1, 2, or 3 units long.  There are 3 single units,  2 double units, and 1 triple unit so 6 triangles on each edge.  4 edges so 24 triangles.

Comment: Hm.. different than how I thought of it... But never the less, your method is significantly easier than my casework.

Comment: but you are missing 12 triangles. They have the main diagonals or a parallel as hypothenusis

Comment: Actually, I am wrong.  The corners with diagonals are also triangles.  Each corner has three diagonals.  So there are 3*4 more.  36 triangles.  I have no idea what "casework" means.

Comment: @fleablood Casework is where you set a case, solve that case, then make another one, solve that case, etc. For example, I used casework by seeing how many "little" triangles there are, then see how many "medium" triangles there are, and so on and on. Then you add all the numbers together to obtain the total number of triangles.

Comment: In general, count the bases.  If the figure is symetric each line with have n single unit bases; n-1 double unit bases, n-k k unit bases, up to 1 n unit bases.  The figure out how many lines have bases.

Comment: Then I *did* solve it by case work . Each edge and corner has triangles.  The edges will have as many triangles as segments.  There are 3 or a unit.  3 -i of i units for $\sum i = 6$ segments for six triangles.  For the corner is a vertix of 1 triangle for each diagonal up to the central diagonal.  There are three so there are three triangles for each corner.

Comment: I just did the case work differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 36 triangles in that square.
[image]